# Aladdin eToken smartcard not showing on keychain access app - OSX High sierra

Tags: objective-c, macos, smartcard, opensc, e-token

I am having Aladdin eToken smart card and installed TokenD using OpenSC package for Mac.But inserted smart card certificate is not showing the in Keycahin access app. do I need to install any additional drivers on Mac?

After OpenSC package installation i tried `/Library/OpenSC/bin/pkcs11-tool --login --test` command but it is throwing `No slot with a token was found.`

FYI: Card is detecting in USB Device Tree.

What is the solution for this to read on keyChain app? Answer will be appreciated.

[image]